# CUPS, shared printer, Windows drivers, point and print

Tags: 14.04, drivers, printing, samba

I know this is a commonly asked question but I'm read up everything I can find, and I think I'm very nearly there!

The setup is:

Headless Ubuntu Trusty machine with CUPS and SAMBA installed, ready to act as a print server for a network printer. Using the web interface, CUPS discovered the network printer by IP address and I found a PDD file for it somewhere.  Installs and prints fine from the web interface; I've set up sharing and things like black and white default.

I've tried adding the printer to my Windows 7 workstation via Add Network Printer, using the format:  `http://machinename:631/printers/printername`  which works fine, but I have to provide the location of the relevant drivers.

If I browse to the machine via Start > Run > `\\machinename` I can see the printer and connect to it that way too, but again I have to point the installer at the drivers.

What I want to deploy is the correct hosting of the drivers inside `\\machinename\print$` so that Windows finds them when you try to connect to the shared printer.

To do this, I explored the print$ share of a Windows machine that currently acts as a print server for the same device (the idea is to replace this Windows machine with the Ubuntu CUPS solution).

In there, I found the expected folders that contained all the driver files, and I copied these to the relevant location on the CUPS machine.

However, even though as a client I can browse and download these drivers, Windows still wants the driver location when I connect to the printer.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`cupsaddsmb` is the missing link here.  There's a (rather old, 2004) how-to in the [Samba manual](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/CUPS-printing.html#id2641105) that covers the exact steps, but there are more recent ones if you search around (like [this one](http://www.geekyprojects.com/ubuntu/getting-windows-printer-drivers-from-cups/) from 2010).  Simplified:

- add a `print$` share in smb.conf if it doesn't already exist
- move the Windows drivers into /usr/share/cups/drv
- run `cupsaddsmb -H localhost -U root -a -v`